# LWC: get value of checkbox on change

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am trying to get the value of a checkbox on change handler.
What I tried so far:

```
<template for:each={objInfo.todoList} for:item='todoListItem' class="slds-p-top_medium">
    <lightning-input 
          key={todoListItem.fieldName} 
          name={todoListItem.fieldName} 
          label={todoListItem.fieldLabel} 
          type={todoListItem.fieldType} 
          value={todoListItem.value} 
          disabled={todoListItem.disabledRes}
          checked={todoListItem.value}                                                
          onchange={handleTodoChange} >
     </lightning-input>
 </template>
```

and

```
handleTodoChange(event) {
    this.value = event.target.value;        
    console.log("Todo: " + event.target.value);
}
```

But no success. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you need to reference `checked` for the `lightning-input` [checkbox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation)

> For input types checkbox and checkbox-button, the value of checked
> attribute.

```
handleTodoChange(event) {
    this.value = event.target.checked;        
    console.log("Todo: " + event.target.checked);
}
```

Comment: omg.. absolute beginners fault.... thanks for pointing this out! But next question: how do I count the amount of checked checkboxes?

Comment: `event.target.name` should work, can you try it?

Comment: Awesome @Oleksandr! Thanks a lot for your support